# Why has excel macro changed its behavior creating book instead of line?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi am new to coding/macro and hoping for some pointing in the right direction.
Using excel 2016 desktop.

I have tried researching problem but am limited knowledge to know what to search for to describe the issue I am having.

I recorded a macro with (Ctrl+n assigned) to add a new line in a worksheet and copy some formulas down (its a record of variations on a project, each time a new variation is requested we add a line to record it).

This was working absolutely fine, until...

I tried a little VBA to 'use sheet name as date' but deleted it as found another way to do what I wanted. Since I deleted this macro the first one (Ctrl+n above) now opens a new workbook instead of adding a new line!

When I run the macro from Macros Dialogue window 'Run' it works fine but if I use 'Ctrl n' it opens a new workbook instead! Please can you help.. Thank You

```
Sub NewVariation()
'
' NewVariation Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+n
'
    Cells.Find(What:="notes", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Rows("10:10").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("I10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("L9:M9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("P9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: isn't ctrl+n the shortcut for making a new workbook? I'm guessing you are interacting with this built in short cut and you should try a different hot key for your macro

Comment: Ive no idea, I did research that and found nothing. However, it had been working fine all week and then not and now is again so I guess the Ctrl+n was not the issue

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved.

I opened the macro dialogue box, highlighted the 'NewVariation' macro and opened 'options' which was showing a blank entry on the 'shortcut key Ctrl+' so I added 'n' and closed the box so it now works.  I have no idea why this made it start working properly again or why its stopped in the first place!

Thank you anyone that was looking to help and would still appreciate an answer as to what has occurred but understand otherwise.

Thank You

Comment: I would definitely recommend using another shortcut besides `Ctrl+N` since this is a registered shortcut for creating a new workbook. This may not mean much to you now, but getting in the habit of overriding existing shortcut keys may lead to frustrating behavior in the future (especially if another user, especially a super user, tries to use your project).